# Is it possible to run an Adobe AIR app without Adobe AIR installed?

Tags: windows, air, installation, adobe

I'm trying to run an **Adobe AIR** app on **Windows 10** *([GameLooper](http://store.steampowered.com/app/435060/GameLooper/))*
and I can't run it, because it requires Adobe AIR which is **not installed** on this computer (which I can't install here). Is it possible to run it without Adobe AIR installation (and without admin privileges)?

Comment: Short answer - no. Isn't there an executable (.exe) version of it included ? Only an .air file ?

Comment: @Philarmon Yes, (GameLooper.exe) but when I run it, it says no Adobe AIR is installed.

Comment: Developer could create standalone versions of application which doesn't require Adobe air installed. But there is no ways for user i think.